# Issue with str.replace() and replace() pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
print(df):
Name
James (C)
Mick
Tash (C)
Liv
Nathan
Chris
```

I am simply trying to get

```
print(df):
James
Mick
Tash
Liv
Nathan
Chris
```

I have tried:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(' (C)','')
```

Which does nothing. and then i also try:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace({'(C)': ''}, inplace=True)
```

Which clears the whole column on output.

Then I tried:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace("[(C)]", "")
```

Which works but it removes any `C` eg `Chris` becomes `hris`

I have looked and these are the main options but they all don't quite work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\` for escape regex, because `()` are special regex characters:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(' \(C\)','')
print (df)
     Name
0   James
1    Mick
2    Tash
3     Liv
4  Nathan
5   Chris
```

Comment: great! thanks very much i think that is working. I also have a name that has `Jason (C,5)` so would i need to use more ` \ ` in that case too?

Comment: @SOK - then use `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(' \(.*\)','')` - removing all values in `()`

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `regex=False` to turn off regex ... `()` are special characters in regex and `str.replace` works on regex by default :

```
df['Name'].str.replace(' (C)','', regex=False)

0     James
1      Mick
2      Tash
3       Liv
4    Nathan
5     Chris
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks @sammywemmy. The first answer I got worked but i tried this and it also works so I appreciate the answer!

Comment: not a problem... @jezrael's solution allows u to extend to more use cases. My aim was just to show why your initial attempt did not work